# Grafana - Mean calculation from dynamic panels inside a dashboard

Tags: prometheus, grafana, grafana-variable, grafana-templating

We have a Grafana dashboard with Prometheus as data source. Inside the dashboard, we have a row that will repeat based on the service(*multi select variable*) selected. The repeated rows will have panels for SLI mean.

My requirement is: I have to find the Mean for all the services(*selected*) in a single panel.

[image: Image 1]

Here ***test-service***, ***test-service-1*** are the values selected from the service variable(multi select). One of the panel inside each row is **5min SLI mean**. Below attached image will show the 5min SLI panel [image]

Inside General Row I need a similar panel, But here SLI calculation should be the mean value of all the other 5min SLI panel.

Say, if 2 services are selected, we will have 2 rows as shown in the attached image. The 5m SLI(inside General row) should be the mean of those two services selected. If 2 more services selected(total 4 service), the 5m SLI panel inside General row should change by calculating mean from 4 other 5min SLI panels.

Note: I am new to Grafana, Sharing some steps/ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus' query language, PromQL, has an `avg` function which will likely do what you want here. Check out https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#aggregation-operators for extended documentation on similar functions.

Let's assume your metric is called `sli`. When you include a Prometheus query `sli` in your Grafana graph, Prometheus picks every instance of that metric and Grafana then displays them.

You can (and I assume you have?) filter this by having a variable in Grafana, and doing a PromQL label selector on that variable, like such: - `sli{service=~"${service}"}`.

What this actually is getting you, though, is a set of time series from Prometheus, which Grafana is handily converting into a chart for you. But you can ask Prometheus to average it for you before Grafana gets its hands on the result:

```
avg(sli{service=~"${service}"})
```

This will return one single time series (instead of many of them) representing the average of the time series selected by `sli{service=~"${service}"}` at every point in time.

I've had to make some assumptions here since you didn't show your query in your initial question; feel free to update your question with more details and drop a comment here if you want me to update the answer.